# Access fragment's view in DrawerItemClickListener (NavigationDrawer) - outside onCreateView()

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I try to get the Fragment's View in the DrawerItemClickListener. But I can't access the right View!

MapFragment:

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    public View rootView;

    public MapFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

DrawerItemClickListener:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        Object myView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    }
}
```

How can I access my 'rootView' in the DrawerItemClickListener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly you don't have to store the view by youself. You can use getView();
Also you can move your code

```
Object myView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
```

into onCreateView, and store Object myView as a field of the class. And then do whatever you need with it in the DrawerItemClickListener

Comment: Thx! I just moved the code to onCreateView() and made myView public `public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 public MapView myView;`